# Why is my heatmap not projecting?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, point, csv, heat-map

I have been having a lot of issues trying to do a heatmap.  At first the data would disappear when I created it, so I figured out that I had to reproject the CRS.  I reprojected it, ran the heatmap, and there was no output.  The screenshot is how the "Coyote_Heat2" heatmap appears in the menu, but as you can see it hasn't created any heat map.  What else could be going wrong?  There were no error messages this time. [image]

Comment: I don't get why the reprojection step is necessary. Which CRS is the original data in? What did you project it to? How did you reproject? What settings did you use when creating the heat map? What happens when you rightclick the heat map and choose "zoom to layer extent"?

Comment: The terms "disappear" and "reproject" in one sentence usually lead to the error, that you did not actually reproject your data, but instead just set their crs?

Comment: There are 2 values in the generated heatmap (around 0 and 1000), so maybe the cell size was (way) too big and you have a 1 cell raster? It would be consistent with @MrXsquared comment: if you just have set the CRS, all your points are within 180 **meters** from 0;0, but a cell size of a few km would cover all points in a single cell

Comment: Originally the file was in ESPG:4236.  I reprojected it to ESPG:4236 because the orignal CRS wasn't linear, and when I tried to make a heatmap it only gave me "degrees" as an option.  I reprojected it by going to vector--data management tools--reproject layer.  Then I tried to run the heatmap.  The original file is a shapefile, not a raster though. Is this the right process? Here is the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13qs0Fwg9qMD1ah1AO8f36554390XNhsz/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not a shapefile, but a csv, containing commas - so a bit tricky to convert to point geometry. After succeeding, data reprojected to EPSG:26915. I didn't take the time to evaluate which CRS to use for this area, there might be better ones for your purpose, so be aware of that!

Heatmap (Kernel density estimation) from toolbox, settings (try different setting): radius 10 km; output raster size: be sure to have a value of rows/colums of several hundred/a few thousands - see an example below. Just a quick and dirty try to get you some ideas where to start. Carefully evaluate the options and try to get an understanding of the theoretical and conceptual background - that's at least as important as proceeding data. This should only be the last step.

Problem: in some parts (around Minneaplois), your points are very close (few hundred meters and less), in other regions (north of Minnesota) there are very few (like hundreds of km distance from one point to the other). So try different settings for radius/output raster size.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Would it be better to clip the area around the Twin Cities metro and create a separate heatmap?

Comment: I clipped it, ran it again, and got this error:Could not create destination layer
Execution failed after 0.04 seconds

Comment: You should post the whole error message - this one here does not say much. Did you reproject (which CRS)? What settings did you use (see screenshot above)

Comment: Would bd great if you could upload a screenshot of what you try - the Heatmap dialog window as mine above. Withoutmore details it' s impossible to say where the problem is

Comment: Yes, clipping is probably the better option here