# What causes the "could not create destination layer" error when creating a heatmap?

Tags: qgis-3, layers, heat-map

I'm using QGIS 3.16.1.  When I try to make a heatmap I got an error message saying "Could not create destination layer." I then tried using a smaller row and column size, and it runs the process, shows an image of the heatmap in the sidebar, but nothing in the main map page.  Here are the settings I used, which are also in the screenshot:
Rows:800
Columns:611
Pixel size X: 129.560036
Pixel size Y:129.50036

The other screenshot is how my screen appears. You can see that the heatmap is turned on but doesn't show anything.  I'm not sure what causes this.  [image]

[image]

Comment: Well, your heatmap would have 999999*790661 pixels each representing 10*10 centimeters. That is a "little" large, no wonder it fails.

Comment: The rows, columns, and pixel sizes were set to whatever the default was.  What should I try changing them to?

Comment: @MrXsquared is right; assuming a 32-bit output, that is a 3 TB output. If you want to determine this for yourself: w * h * bit-depth / 8 / 1024 / 1024 = size in MB, i.e. 999999 * 790661 * 32 / 8 / 1024 / 1024 = ~3,016,129 MB

Comment: Please read this answer: "output raster size: be sure to have a value of rows/colums of several hundred/a few thousands", including a screenshot- you ignored that: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/381564/88814

Comment: Don't trust default values, always think yourself. Defaults are seldom what fits your data best.

Comment: I changed the values to be a lot lower, and it creates a heatmap icon but nothing shows up in the map for it now.  The third screenshot is what it looks like.

Comment: What "value" is "a lot lower". How much is that? Pixel size? Row no.? Radius? Did you try the settings exactly as in the screenshot I linked in the comment above? Please understand that no one can help you without very precise information about what you did and what settings you used.

Comment: If your 4th screenshot is anew one, not that @MrXsquared refered to, than your pixel size is still way too small (0.1, meaning 10cm in a CRS using meters). Please try to implement all the recomandations in the comments above and come back if they fail - but please include information about what settings produced which kind of probem

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I edited it to include the screenshots and the dimensions I used.  Larger pixel sizes don't seem to change the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a radius of 100 meters: so around every point QGIS draws a circle of 100 meters radius. Of course, when you are zooming out, these pixel-circles can't be seen: zoom in close enough to see them.

Otherwise increase radius. Try 1000 meters, 10000 meters or more - the higher the value, the more of your map will be covered by the heatmap. But in the same time, the more diffuse your results get. Finding an optimal solution is trial and error. Get used to this kind of processing and try to understand how the pixels are created from the points.

Also be sure to always check radius AND pixel size before running the tool.

Playing around with the Heatmap rendering symbology of the points layer may help you to better understand how changing values for radius influence the output.
See the screenshot, I used your coyote dataset: radius set to 10.000 map units [=meters] shows small circles, which almost disappear when you set the value to 100 (zoom in to see them!). If you set the value to 1.000.000 (= 1000 km!) however, you won't see but one very large circle all covering all your map canvas. Both setting apparently are not very useful. To get good results, you should also consider:

1. CRS (should be an equal area projection - not the case in my screenshot, so don't stick to that, find a useful CRS for your region of interest)
2. consider the properties of your data: how far is the range of "influence" of each point, what does a point represent and to what degree can you "merge" different points to an "aggregated" visualization?
3. What does "density" mean, for which area should it be relvant - thus what "resolution" do you want: one value for all of the state? Individual density for every acre? In the first case, there will be no "patterns", as density is the same everywhere. In the second case, you probably have too much information and the heatmap is not really improving the understanding of your individual points.

[image]

The larger you set the radius, the less you can identify local clusters. To make an example: As you can see, a value of 50.000 (=50 km) gives "nice" results for the whole extent of Minnesota - however, there are some issues with that:

[image]

When you zoom in, you can see that there are areas with a very high density locally (Cedar Creek NHA in this case, turquoise circle in the screenshot), whereas large areas (rectangles) do not have one single point. However, the heatmap assigns the same "density value" to the whole area because I set the radius to 50 km - so the points in the Cedar Creek NHA influence the density in the whole area of 50 km around it - this is probably not what you want.

[image]

Setting the radius to 5000 (5km) for the same region and without changing anything else, you get this result - quite different for exactly the same data. That's why reflecting what data you have, what you want to do with it and what your workflow makes with your input is so crucial. You can get almost any kind of visualization out of your data, but hat's not the point. Output should be meaningful. What that exactly means must be decided in every single case. This is not about software and data processing, but conceptual work that you should carefully consider before you use any tool.

Also reflect about the quality of your data (representing coyote sightings, as you stated elswhere). What do these points represent: "coyotes" or "sightings"? To be clear: there might be a lot of coyotes out there somewhere where no human is observing them, thus in that areas, you have no points. In other parts (inhabited areas, parks and so on), observation is probably a lot more intensive. So reflect how the data you have was created - and what is maybe lacking. Coyotes living near humans are easier to "measure" (register) than those living in the wilderness. So creating a heatmap can be tricky and might lead to wrong conclusions without critcal interpretation.

[image]